# Why does an AWS website have 3 servers in dnschecker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns-server

When I test a client's website in dnschecker.org it shows 3 IP addresses. Is this something to do with how amazon hosts websites? Other sites I check have only one.

Comment: That is called "round-robin DNS" and adequately explained on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS and not Amazon specific (Amazon's Route 53 DNS provides arguably much better solutions than such "simple" round robin DNS)

Comment: Great, I understand. So if I were to change the A record in route 53, should that successfully repoint the DNS to the new IP, bypassing the round robin DNS, or do I need to change three A records?

Comment: Did you set the DNS for this site?  How is it hosted? Whoever did set three IPs in the A record.  That's perfectly acceptable, as the commenter above indicated.

Comment: I inherited the setup - and am moving away from AWS for now. There are two A records in route 52 - an alias to a load balancer, and an alias to the www address. I’m just trying to find out will changing the two A records in route 53 be enough to move away, or do I need to do anything else. Delete the load balancer, change the NS and SOA records etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer summarises the comments above, so people don't come in and try to help, as it's not marked answered.

**Multiple A Records**

Multiple A records is [round robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS), a type of load balancing. It relies on the client making requests based on round robin, rather than just using the first entry.

**Moving away from AWS**

To move away from AWS you simply delete your current public records (A / Alias) and put in new A records with the new IP address.

**Backups**

Suggest you export all data from the instances, databases and data, or even do a backup of the instance you can keep outside of AWS. You'll want something like Restic or Macrium reflect, as AWS doesn't make this easy.

**Cleaning an AWS Account**

Next I suggest you stop your EC2 / RDS instances, but don't terminate them, in case something goes wrong with the new website. After a few days of the new website working you might create a snapshot of your EC2 instances / backup of your RDS instances and delete the instance, as snapshots are cheaper than instances. After a month you may want to delete all resources in AWS, to save the cost. There will probably be resources all over the place - EC2 / RDS snapshots and backups, S3 buckets, lambda functions, etc. Cleaning an AWS account could be tricky, so if it's not required for something else just close the account.